# Ingresar atributos de instancia por posición - Python

Tags: python, poo, clase, atributos, usercontrol

Ya tengo definida mi clase con sus atributos de instancia, ahora quiero crear un nuevo objeto y por teclado ir agregando la información:

```
class Persona():
    
    # Atributos de instancia
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, dni):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.dni = dni
```

Entonces hago lo siguiente y todo funciona bien:

```
# Ingreso de datos por teclado
humano_01 = Persona(
            str(input("Ingrese su nombre: ")), 
            int(input("Ingrese su edad: ")), 
            int(input("Ingrese su DNI sin puntos: ")))
```

Lo que quiero es usar try-except en cada una de los inputs, para que, si por ejemplo en "nombre" ingreso un número, lo pueda detectar y pedir el nombre correcto, lo mismo que en "edad" solo pueda ingresar un número entero, el programa detecte el error y pida corregirlo.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Y  cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, Lo menciona en el párrafo final, quiere hacer validación de datos para que solicite al usuario ingresar el tipo de dato correcto en caso de que ingrese alguna otra cosa